# *** numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)

Tags: python, numba

I am having a problem with `UMAP(...).transform()`. I loaded the model with `trans = pickle.load()`.

```
ipdb> trans                                                                                                                                 
UMAP(a=None, angular_rp_forest=False, b=None, init='spectral',
   learning_rate=1.0, local_connectivity=1.0, metric='correlation',
   metric_kwds=None, min_dist=0.5, n_components=3, n_epochs=None,
   n_neighbors=3, negative_sample_rate=5, random_state=None,
   repulsion_strength=1.0, set_op_mix_ratio=1.0, spread=1.0,
   target_metric='categorical', target_metric_kwds=None,
   target_n_neighbors=-1, target_weight=0.5, transform_queue_size=4.0,
   transform_seed=42, verbose=False)
```

As UMAP uses `numba` package, I got a problem with resolving types. Here is the error shown.

```
ipdb> trans.transform(X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], -1))                                                                                  
*** numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of type(CPUDispatcher(<function rdist at 0x7f36c7ce4e18>)) with parameters (array(float32, 1d, C), array(float64, 1d, C))
Known signatures:
 * (array(float32, 1d, A), array(float32, 1d, A)) -> float32
 * parameterized
[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function rdist at 0x7f36c7ce4e18>))
[2] During: typing of call at /home/infinity/anaconda3/envs/HFT/lib/python3.6/site-packages/umap/umap_.py (776)


File "../../../anaconda3/envs/HFT/lib/python3.6/site-packages/umap/umap_.py", line 776:
def optimize_layout(
    <source elided>

                dist_squared = rdist(current, other)
                ^

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

Here is a `X_test` sample :

```
array([[[-7.84867750e-05, -3.92410776e-05, -1.17713994e-04, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -5.88910810e-05],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
          3.22361913e+01,  3.36224857e+01,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-1.17741714e-04, -1.56979711e-04,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
         -3.22361913e+01, -3.36224857e+01, -2.35599012e-04],
        ...,
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  3.92395378e-05],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]],

       [[ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  7.98615775e-04, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -2.66778461e-04],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.10377388e-03,  1.86421709e-03,  3.04066897e-04, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  5.52533571e-04],
        ...,
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.14074947e-04,  3.80220908e-05, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [-1.36996749e-03, -4.18338442e-04, -4.18322533e-04, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -1.21918711e-03],
        [-3.80814562e-05, -1.10373187e-03, -3.80380000e-05, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -1.90615976e-05]]])
```

X.shape is `(5839, 45, 41)`

How can I fix that type error?

**UPDATE**

I notified that the problem is with

```
@numba.njit("f4(f4[:],f4[:])", fastmath=True)
def rdist(x, y):
    """Reduced Euclidean distance.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: array of shape (embedding_dim,)
    y: array of shape (embedding_dim,)

    Returns
    -------
    The squared euclidean distance between x and y
    """
    result = 0.0
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        result += (x[i] - y[i]) ** 2

    return result

x = [-4.3200183,   0.2443985,   0.24419938]
y = [-3.7033827,   0.91038215,  4.292648  ]

test = rdist(x,y)
```

However, I am unqualified to fix the problem.

If I run the above code, I got the following error `TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) reflected list(float64), reflected list(float64)`

Comment: What is a real example for the input data? You are passing a list to the function, but you declared two 1d array of float32 as input. Apart from that the algorithm can be improved, if your arrays are big.